# Main Breaktroughts in Neuroscience in the past decade [2014-2023]

Tags: neuroscience

I just finished an online introductory course on neurobiology, dated 2014. Given the fast pace of progress in research in science in the last decade, I wonder if any of the core principles known to neuroscience from 2014 has been modified, or if significant new findings have been made or any advancements have been made to cure major diseases. To make the question answerable, I'm referring only to major findings that could be presented in a future introductory course.

Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: This is kind of open for discussion, and I would ask you to add your own research and findings to steer the answer in a certain direction you want it to go. Without that, the question lacks the necessary focus and is not suitable for this site.

Comment: Hi @AliceD, any introductory websites you would suggest? Thanks

Comment: Quite frankly, no. Have you Googled?

Answer (score 0):

I will give it a shot, even though I would appreciate a reply from a more experienced fellow. :)

- **The rise of Neurogenetics**, thanks to cheaper cost of DNA sequencing.
- **Brain-Computer Interfaces** and neural implants.
- **The rise of optogenetics and chemogenetics**: These techniques, which allow researchers to control the activity of specific neurons using light or drugs, respectively, have revolutionized our ability to probe the function of neural circuits.
- **Advancements in neuroimaging**: The development of new imaging techniques like CLARITY and expansion microscopy, which enable high-resolution, three-dimensional imaging of large volumes of brain tissue, has transformed our ability to visualize neural circuits and their activity.
- **The microbiome and the brain**: The influence of the gut microbiome on the brain and behavior, a field often referred to as the "gut-brain axis," has emerged as a major new area of research. Studies have linked changes in the gut microbiota to a variety of neurological and psychiatric conditions, including autism, depression, and neurodegenerative diseases.
- **Use of AI techniques** to study the brain.
- **Expanded knowledge of glial cells**: Glial cells like astrocytes and microglia are now recognized as more active participants in brain function compared to older views.

Overall, no radical overturning of core principles have happened.

Sources:

- https://singularityhub.com/2020/01/05/these-breakthroughs-made-the-2010s-the-decade-of-the-brain/
- https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/10-big-ideas-in-10-years-of-brain-science/
- GPT4, Claude2